# AccountKit User needs to verify Everytime to login?

Tags: php, facebook

I am using Facebook AccountKit to login users with SMS and Emails. SMS Login is simple user have to enter the OTP and then he can login to our website. But in case of Login with Email. AccountKit sends a verification link to users email and after verifying he can login to account. Now in this case if a user wants to login he will have to verify his email id everytime. Is there any way where we can skip the verification part everytime and just match the Id and email ID to login ?

I am using Elaniin code for the Account Kit API.

```
    <?php
// function to verify session status
function is_session_started()
{
    if ( php_sapi_name() !== 'cli' ) {
        if ( version_compare(phpversion(), '5.4.0', '>=') ) {
            return session_status() === PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE ? TRUE : FALSE;
        } else {
            return session_id() === '' ? FALSE : TRUE;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
// verifying POST data and adding the values to session variables
if(isset($_POST["code"])){
  session_start();
  $_SESSION["code"] = $_POST["code"];
  $_SESSION["csrf_nonce"] = $_POST["csrf_nonce"];
  $ch = curl_init();
  // Set url elements
  $fb_app_id = '465871913602533';
  $ak_secret = 'eab92d7c75f08c6e95a48341c80b3ffc';
  $token = 'AA|'.$fb_app_id.'|'.$ak_secret;
  // Get access token
  $url = 'https://graph.accountkit.com/v1.0/access_token?grant_type=authorization_code&code='.$_POST["code"].'&access_token='.$token;
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  $result=curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  $info = json_decode($result);
  // Get account information
  $url = 'https://graph.accountkit.com/v1.0/me/?access_token='.$info->access_token;
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  $result=curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  $final = json_decode($result);  
}
?>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Login with Account Kit</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="ak-icon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
  <!--Hotlinked Account Kit SDK-->
  <script src="https://sdk.accountkit.com/en_EN/sdk.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
// verifying if the session exists
if(is_session_started() === FALSE && !isset($_SESSION)){
?>
<h1 class="ac">Login with Account Kit</h1>
<p class="ac">This example shows you how to implement<br>Facebook Account Kit for web using PHP.</p>
<div class="buttons">
  <button onclick="phone_btn_onclick();">Login with SMS</button>
  <button onclick="email_btn_onclick();">Login with Email</button>
</div>
<form action="" method="POST" id="my_form">
  <input type="hidden" name="code" id="code">
  <input type="hidden" name="csrf_nonce" id="csrf_nonce">
</form>
<?php
}else{
?>
<h1 class="ac">Login with Account Kit</h1>
<p class="ac">The session with Facebook Account Kit is already started.</p>
<h3 class="ac">Your Information</h3>
<p class="ac">
  <!-- show account information -->
  <strong>ID:</strong> <?=$final->id?> <br>
  <?php
  if(isset($final->email)){
  ?>
  <strong>Email:</strong> <?=$final->email->address?>
  <?php
  }else{
  ?>
  <strong>Country Code:</strong> +<?=$final->phone->country_prefix?> <br>
  <strong>Phone Number:</strong> <?=$final->phone->national_number?> 
  <?php
  }
  ?>  
</p>
<div class="buttons">
  <button onclick="logout();">Logout</button>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
<script>
  // initialize Account Kit with CSRF protection
  AccountKit_OnInteractive = function(){
    AccountKit.init(
      {
        appId:465871913602533,         
        state:"abcd", 
        version:"v1.0"
      }
      //If your Account Kit configuration requires app_secret, you have to include ir above
    );
  };
  // login callback
  function loginCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
    if (response.status === "PARTIALLY_AUTHENTICATED") {
      document.getElementById("code").value = response.code;
      document.getElementById("csrf_nonce").value = response.state;
      document.getElementById("my_form").submit();
    }
    else if (response.status === "NOT_AUTHENTICATED") {
      // handle authentication failure
      console.log("Authentication failure");
    }
    else if (response.status === "BAD_PARAMS") {
      // handle bad parameters
      console.log("Bad parameters");
    }
  }
  // phone form submission handler
  function phone_btn_onclick() {
    // you can add countryCode and phoneNumber to set values
    AccountKit.login('PHONE', {}, // will use default values if this is not specified
      loginCallback);
  }
  // email form submission handler
  function email_btn_onclick() {  
    // you can add emailAddress to set value
    AccountKit.login('EMAIL', {}, loginCallback);
  }
  // destroying session
  function logout() {
        document.location = 'logout.php';
  }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Every time that a person logs in to Account Kit on a new device a person would need to go through the verification flow. This is the same for SMS or Email - the verification is done via the SMS code or clicking through the email link. 

Once you get an access token for a given person finishing logging in you can keep them logged in as long as the access token is valid.